# How to make an A.C. voltage source (low voltage) with desired frequency from a D.C. source?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, ac, safety, low-power

I want to make an A.C. source with desired voltage and frequency (adjustable) from D.C. sources like batteries.

I tried to search circuits on the internet, but as I am relatively new in the field (especially A.C. circuits,) I couldn't find one satisfying my need. I require the circuit diagram for verifying and demonstrating high school physics concepts like resonance etc.

I don't intend to draw a ton of power from the source, so including low cost but reasonably reliable components is highly appreciated.  I specifically want low A.C. voltage and not 220V or 120V, safe enough for me to play around and experiment, so according to my limited knowledge I think a transformer should be avoided as I don't want high voltages.

Providing a circuit diagram or complete idea of the circuit with the name of parts for the above is highly helpful, and will really help me create projects, demonstrations and tinkering them this winter vacation.

Edit:

Required voltage range : anything between 9V RMS to 30V RMS (one fixed value is needed, I don't need to change the voltage) or whatever that does not shock but gets the job done.

Waveform: any waveform, but sine is actually always desirable for high school student but anything will do.

Current draw:  <50mA is more than enough already , so at maximum 100mA needed.

Frequency: 50Hz to 1KHz , is enough.

Comment: schmitt trigger CMOS clock and a FET power half bridge IC is all you need. You choose Vdd and Id max and add heatsink. Then get 2 for bipolar square voltages= full bridge. Sine wave is more work.

Comment: You would need to at least specify the voltage, current and frequency range you require and also the waveform, eg sine, square, triangular.

Comment: @HandyHowie ok I have edited the question

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75  Thanks a lot for the suggestion I will try learning more about those and how to implement it thanks once again.

Comment: Do you have a computer that you can use at home for your experiments?

Comment: Class D switched half-bridge into LC low Q filter can generate sines depends on load R

Comment: @JRE yes i do but (1) computeristic simulations are less fun than real ones (2) I cannot submit my projects to teachers (3) I don't know apps for circuit simulations, it would be good if you share name(s) of such softwares.     But yes it is a cost effective and safe way , It might be extremely useful but I havent used any yet.

Comment: I was not going to suggest a simulation.  I think people need to use real hardware to learn about how things work.  I'll post an answer in a little while.  It may take me an hour or two to get back to this, though.  Check back later.  I will answer today.

Comment: @JRE I am eagerly waiting, Highly Appreciated , Thanks a lot for putting so much work, No words to thank you enough.

Comment: What frequency do you want? Mains-type frequency 50 or 60 Hz, or much higher?

Comment: @Neil_UK yes 50 Hz to 1kHz max, and I want to adjust it.

Comment: Buy a second-hand 100 W audio amplifier, and a cheap DDS to drive it.

Comment: The nice thing about simulations is monitoring Pd in each lossy component without Arrhenius effects of destroying parts. So you learn how to soften the effects while improving efficiency and yet dampen the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you not build a signal generator as your first project.  The circuit you described is a signal generator.  The difficulties involved are greater than you can imagine.

You are just beginning to work with electronics:

- You don't know what things are important or difficult.
- You won't have tools to build the things you need.
- You don't have the equipment to test the things you build.

I would suggest instead that you use the equipment at hand:  your computer.

- Any modern computer has a sound output.
- Any modern computer has a sound input.

Use your computer as the signal generator.  Use your computer to view the output of the signal generator.

You will need just a few things to do this:

1. A so called "Aux" cable.  This is a small cable with a 1/8 inch stereo plug at each end.
2. Some free software.  I recommend [Purr Data](https://github.com/agraef/purr-data/releases).  It can easily generate any audio signal through the line-out of your computer and display what comes in through the line-in.  It is free, and available for Windows, macOS, and Linux.

An aux cable can be bought just about anywhere.  They are often used to connect audio players (MP3 devices) to amplifiers.

This is an aux cable:

[image]

Get such a cable and use it to connect the blue and green jacks on the back of your computer.

Download and install Purr Data, then follow the [Purr Data Introduction](https://agraef.github.io/purr-data-intro/Purr-Data-Intro.html) to get it running.

Copy the following code into a text editor (the simple Notepad in Windows) and save it as demo.pd

```
#N canvas 0 29 1280 972 12;
#X obj 59 147 dac~;
#X obj 454 30 adc~;
#N canvas 0 0 450 300 (subpatch) 0;
#X array scope 1000 float 4 black black;
#X coords 0 1 999 -1 1158 591 1;
#X restore 58 233 graph;
#X obj 452 186 tabwrite~ scope;
#X obj 407 143 bng 15 250 50 0 empty empty empty 17 7 0 10 -262144
-1 -1;
#X obj 453 91 hip~ 1;
#X obj 58 110 osc~ 1000 0;
#X obj 59 44 hsl 128 15 30 10000 0 0 empty empty empty -2 -8 0 10 -262144
-1 -1 3150 1;
#X floatatom 89 73 8 0 0 0 - - -, f 8;
#X text 60 12 Generator;
#X text 347 17 Capture;
#X obj 475 140 threshold~ 0.001 20 -0.001 20;
#X connect 1 0 5 0;
#X connect 4 0 3 0;
#X connect 5 0 3 0;
#X connect 5 0 11 0;
#X connect 6 0 0 0;
#X connect 6 0 0 1;
#X connect 7 0 8 0;
#X connect 7 0 6 0;
#X connect 8 0 6 0;
#X connect 11 0 3 0;
```

(Make sure you save it as demo.pd not as demo.pd.txt.  Windows messes with things.)

Load the pd file in Purr Data and start the audio running.

With the aux cable plugged in you should see something like this:

[image]

Run the slider in the generator section up and down.  You'll see the frequency change (the width of the waves.)  The amplitude (the height) will stay the same.
Now unplug the aux cable, cut it in two, and strip the ends of the wires you find inside.  You'll end up with two cables like this one:

[image]

The silvery one is the ground.  The other two carry the signals.

For a first test, wire the two cables back together so that you get the same sine wave picture back on the display.

Now disconnect them again, and wire them like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4SLnk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Run the frequency up and down again and you'll see the amplitude (height) change.

You can connect your inductor/capacitor circuits between those two points and see the effects of the LC resonance by changing the frequency.

You can't accurately measure the change, but you can see it and get a "feel" for how it works.

Calculate your LC circuits for resonances between 100 hertz and 10000 hertz.  In the middle somewhere is best - you can see what happens above and below the resonance frequency.

---

In the example above, the slider for the generator runs from 30 Hz to 10kHz.  You can change that if you need to.

The wire colors inside your aux cable may be different.  Just use matching pairs.  The ground wire will (almost) always be obviously different.  If you can't identify it on yours, ask for help.

---

This generates low level audio signals - around 1V RMS.  It's not what you specified, but it is easy to do and easy to work with.

Comment: Oh That is even better than my initial idea, That is incredibly cool, Thanks a lot, I will do it right now, Thanks !!!

Comment: Try it out.  Get things working at least to the stage of showing the sine wave.  I'll be gone for a while.  Leave a comment if you have trouble.  Heck, leave a comment if you **don't** have trouble.  Let me know how it works out.

Comment: @MissMulan Its ok if it works out and satisfies the need , the requirements above by me are arbitrary just a approximate needs, I just need an Low Voltage A.C. Source with adjustable freq, and if it does that there is no problem.

Comment: @MissMulan can you explain what is actually wrong with this answer?

Comment: @ManavSengupta:  Good to hear it is working.

Comment: @JRE Yess! it worked, Thanks a ton, See: https://ibb.co/F0thd7H. Just need some tips so i dont fry my pc, as I Love my PC. But yes it is 100% working. I used pure data as purr data was being deleted by my antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Any of simple one-transistor LC oscillator can do the job for 1kHz to 1Mhz range. Place buffer after output to get 100mA current capability. A frequency tuning can be added using variable capacitor.

Comment: I am sorry , I couldnt Imagine or draw the circuit you mentioned, also my bad I didnot mention the frequency before, I need 50Hz to 1KHz max (adjustable)